# ASP.net Ajax Enabled WCF Service - Security issue

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-ajax, wcf-security

I've got a problem with an AJAX Enabled WCF service.

The service is configured as follows:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="secureWebHttpBinding">
       <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
         <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"></transport>
       </security>
     </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Shared.Services.AjaxServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Shared.Services.AjaxServiceServiceBehaviour">
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
        <service name="Shared.Services.AjaxService" behaviorConfiguration="Shared.Services.AjaxServiceServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Shared.Services.AjaxServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" bindingConfiguration="secureWebHttpBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Shared.Services.AjaxService">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The security problem occurs when the application is deployed on the production environment (IIS 7).

When I request the url to the ajax service "serviceName.svc/js" a windows credential prompt appears. Even though when I request "serviceName.svc" the service description page is displayed properly. Could it be that IIS recognized .../js as a sub directory which doesn't physically exists and due to that it doesn't know which security setting should be applied? I also enabled all authentication types for the directory and service in the IIS administration page. Plus I enabled anonymous access for that location via the web.config. The whole application is an intranet app and is protected by windows authentication btw.

Thanks in advance